# Creating a property of strict generic type of "self"

Tags: swift, generics

I want to create a property on a class that uses the class type as a generic parameter, and I'm having difficulty working it out.

```
open class ResponseProcessor {

  required public init() {

  }

  var success: ((_ responseProcessor: ResponseProcessor) -> Void)?

  func process() {

    success?(self)

  }

}

class TestProcessor: ResponseProcessor {

  var result: String?

  override func process() {

    result = "Some Result"

    super.process()

  }

}

open class Request<ResponseProcessorType: ResponseProcessor> {

  var success: ((_ responseProcessor: ResponseProcessor) -> Void)?

  func doRequest() {

    let responseProcessor = ResponseProcessorType.init()
    responseProcessor.success = success
    responseProcessor.process()

  }

}

class TestRequest: Request<TestProcessor> {

}

let testRequest = TestRequest()
testRequest.success = { (responseProcessor) in
  // This line reports an error, but I want it to know what 
  // type the responseProcessor is.
  print(responseProcessor.result) 

}
testRequest.doRequest()
```

I want to be able to assign SubRequest to the `.request` variable, but I can't because of strict generic typing.

So I'd like to be able to say "the `request` property on a `ResponseProcessor` should be of type `Request<WhateverThisClassIs>`, but I can't work out how to express that, or declare it in a way that works.

It should work out that `testProcessor.request` is of type `HTTPRequest<TestProcessor>`, but obviously that isn't happening.

Comment: What do you want your calling code to look like if this worked the way you would like it to? What algorithm would read `testProcessor.request` and what would it do with the value? Why the circular dependency between ResponseProcessor and Request? That's very awkward. What common currency (URLResponse, URLRequest, Data) could you use that the processor would work on? Starting with the use case (the calling code) will drive what your types should look like. Swift does not have a way to express generic covariance, but it's not clear that's what you really want here anyway.

Comment: @RobNapier I've made the use case more realistic - I was attempting to simplify it for readability.

Comment: You mention a `request` Variable but in your code there are none. Could you please clarify on that?

Comment: When you say "I want it to know what type the responseProcessor is," is that what you really mean? You really want to know the type of the responseProcessor? (Because that's trivial: `type(of: responseProcessor)`.) Or do you really mean you want to *do* something with `result`? What do you want to do with `result`? What would the next line of code that isn't `print` look like?

Comment: In your updated code, the problem isn't generics at all. It's that `success` passes a `ResponseProcessor`, and `ResponseProcessor` doesn't have a `result` property. So what would this look like if it were *just* `TestRequest` and no classes or generics or anything else. What would it do, and what would something that isn't `TestRequest` do. How do they duplicate code? And from there, we can extract an abstraction. Write the concrete versions first.

Comment: BTW, from your text, you indicate that you're trying to build a `HTTPRequest` with some kind of (I assume arbitrary) processor. Composible and testable HTTP systems are pretty straightforward using Swift protocols, and I'm happy to post code that does that if that's the real question. It just depends on what you want the top-level API to look like.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to answer your question or not, but maybe it will put you on a better road. To your stated question, the answer is there is no generic covariance in Swift. What you're trying to write is not possible. Generic covariance wouldn't actually fix your code, because you have a lot of other type problems here (your latest version is probably violating Liskov's Substitution Principle, which means it breaks the meaning of class inheritance). But I don't think you actually want what you're trying to write at all.

I suspect you're writing a pluggable and testable networking stack. That's really common. He's a fairly simple one; they can get much more powerful if you tear this apart a bit more.

First, the low-level networking stack itself should consume URLRequests and return Data. That's all. It should not try to deal with model types. This is where people always go off the rails. So a Request is an URLRequest and a completion handler:

```
struct Request {
    let urlRequest: URLRequest
    let completion: (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void
}
```

And a client consumes those.

```
final class NetworkClient {
    func fetch(_ request: Request) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request.urlRequest) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error { request.completion(.failure(error)) }
            else if let data = data { request.completion(.success(data)) }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Now we generally don't want to talk to URLSession when we're testing. We want to throw back pre-canned data probably. So we make one of those.

```
final class TestClient {
    enum ClientError: Error {
        case underflow
    }
    var responses: [Result<Data, Error>]
    init(responses: [Result<Data, Error>]) { self.responses = responses }
    func fetch(_ request: Request) {
        if let response = responses.first {
            responses.removeFirst()
            request.completion(response)
        } else {
            request.completion(.failure(ClientError.underflow))
        }
    }
}
```

I'm marking things `final class` because these are sensibly reference types, but I want to make it clear that I'm not using class inheritance anywhere here. (Feel free to leave "final" off in your own code; it's a bit pedantic and usually not needed.)

How are these two things alike? They share a protocol:

```
protocol Client {
    func fetch(_ request: Request)
}
```

Great. Now I can do things like:

```
let client: Client = TestClient(responses: [])
```

No associated types means that `Client` is perfectly fine as a type.

But getting back Data is kind of ugly. We want a type, like User.

```
struct User: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

How do we do that? We just need a way to construct a Request that fetches a Decodable:

```
extension Request {
    init<Model: Decodable>(fetching: Model.Type,
                           from url: URL,
                           completion: @escaping (Result<Model, Error>) -> Void) {
        self.urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.completion = { data in
            completion(Result {
                try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data.get())})
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how Request still doesn't know anything about models? And Client doesn't know anything about models. There's just this Request initializer that takes a Model type and wraps it up in a way that can accept Data and spit back a Model.

You can take this approach miles further. You can write a Client that wraps a Client and modifies the request, adding headers for example.

```
struct AddHeaders: Client {
    let base: Client
    let headers: [String: String]

    func fetch(_ request: Request) {
        var urlRequest = request.urlRequest
        for (key, value) in headers {
            urlRequest.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }

        base.fetch(Request(urlRequest: urlRequest,
                           completion: request.completion))
    }
}

let client = AddHeaders(base: NetworkClient(),
                        headers: ["Authorization": "Token ...."])
```

There are no subclasses here, no generic types, just one protocol (which has no associated types), and one generic method. But you can plug in a wide variety of back-ends, and compose together any operation that can be made to match one of a handful of transforms (Request -> Request, Request -> Data, Data -> Void).

I hope this matches some of what you're getting at with your question. Best of luck.